# How can I print predefined value in select for DateTime in twig?

Tags: symfony, datetime, twig, symfony-forms, formbuilder

I develop Symfony 3.2 web-application. For some reason I need to print predefined value from database to a custom DateTime field in Twig.
Now I have the following code, but it doesn't work as well:

```
 {{ form_row(form.dateFrom, {attr: {value: parsedData.dateFrom|date}}) }}
```

I used Symfony Forms for this purpose and builder has the following view:

```
       $builder   
         ->add('date', DateType::class, array(
            'mapped'   => false
        ));
```

But that outputs the following:

[image: Default date select]

In HTML I received next code:

```
<div id="date_from" class="form-inline">
    <select id="date_from_day" name="date[from][day]" class="form-control" value="04.12.2017">
        <option value="1">01</option>
        <option value="2">02</option>
        <option value="3">03</option>
     ...
     </select>
 </div>
```

I suppose that there is some stupid mistake, but can't find, where. Could you please help me to handle this issue?

Comment: you should be printing `form.date` instead of `form.dateFrom` in twig,  as your form builder has 'date'

Comment: A `value` on a `select` makes no sense to me. Why do you set `mapped` to false?